# CSS and Navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to do a couple things with my navigation.

1. I would like the width of it to be across the entire boxed width of the website instead of having to use padding to get it to center.
2. When it resizes, I would like the text to get smaller rather than the nav bar stacking until it converts to the mobile menu.

I'm using Cherry Framework, and it's been really quirky with the CSS changes. Any help is much appreciated.[website link](http://www.northeastrunningclub.org)

[website front page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKSL.jpg)

Comment: if you want to do this *right*, you will have to alter your html structure, relatively drastically - what you are asking is for someone to essentially build your elements and style them for you - *not really* a specific problem looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Change your media query rules (themes/CherryFramework/css/style.css line 30) to look something like this, then all the options will be on the same line.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    ...
    .sf-menu > li > a {
        font: normal 10px/1px Oswald;
        color: #314294;
    }
}
```

Picture: [image]